.NET HTTP request on Windows takes a very long time
I have a very simple HTTP request like this:
    public async Task<AccountInfo> GetMyAccountInfoAsync()
    {
        var token = await auth.GetIdTokenAsync(false);

        using var req = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get, "https://my-company-domain.com/api/protected");
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        var http = new HttpClient();
        using var res = await http.SendAsync(req); // Slow here
        res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Irrelevant code
    }

For some reason, when the app runs this code, it takes exactly 43s (+- some ms) to complete:


Interestingly, if I send a request to https://example.com or https://stackoverflow.com with the same code, it's very fast so I suspect something is wrong with DNS resolve. I have tried the following fixes but no use:

Use a brand new HttpClient instance like in the above code, or use a shared single instance from DI (original code).

Running the same request in cUrl takes about 1 second. Therefore this cannot be due to my company's server because I already started it and any requests from cUrl take a very short time.

Wrapped the above code within a Task.Run because I thought maybe running it on the Main/UI thread is not good. The issue still happens.


Also why it takes exactly 43 seconds to complete that request baffles me. The response otherwise is good, it gets the 200 OK and the expected body. What could be the issue? Please advise any debugging I can do to find out more details if needed.
This issue does not happen to Android or iOS.
Update:

Very likely an ISP issue. I used a VPN and the problem does not happen anymore. Does not explain why cUrl does not have this issue though. Similarly, I had a client who couldn't use Nuget in Canada unless he uses VPN but everything outside of .NET is fine. dotnet nuget wouldn't work but using the standalone nuget.exe from the website is fine though. AFAIK, they are different. He could run nuget restore so the packages get cached and then use dotnet restore but if dotnet restore needs to download anything, it fails.

The same code runs in a new Console app has the same issue as well, so it looks like a .NET Windows issue. Still, it takes about 43s to run as well.

My DNS is set to Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 with DNS over TLS enabled. I don't know if .NET uses the same DNS config though.

When I break during the long period:




This must be a system-wide issue because I tried this in PowerShell and it takes a very long time as well:

$http = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
$http.GetStringAsync("https://company-domain.com/api/protected").GetAwaiter().GetResult()


Have you tried a profiler, or attaching a debugger and break into it when it "hangs".

@AloisKraus I am not sure how to use a profiler for this one. I added a screenshot of the tasks when pausing when it hangs.

You're using http client wrong and it will eventually destabilize your software.. Make life easy; use Flurl library

@flackoverstow how is that wrong? I am sharing a single instance of HttpClient throughout the app like documented. Also the problem happens to Powershell and a full PC restart didn't help as well.

My bet is on IPv6 misbehaving.

@AKX you are correct! Disabling IPv6 and the issue goes away. Now to find out why...

@LukeVo I am sharing a single instance of HttpClient throughout the app - Hmm. I thought the code in the post said var http = new HttpClient();. Maybe I was mistaken.

@LukeVo: ConnectToTcpAsync seems to be stuck. If enable unmanaged debugging you should see if e.g. proxy resolution hangs or something like that inside the unmanaged http stack (GetProxyForUrl and friends). You can also check the stuck task which IP is resolved. Last you can profile in the debugger break in Diagnostic Tools. There you should be able to select a profiler or some other tracing (e.g. IntelliTrace you have Enterprise edition).
